# Why does my dash app not update correctly?

Tags: python-3.x, plotly-dash

I'm new to building Dash apps.  The idea is that a user inputs as many stock tickers separated by commas as they wish.  The result is a table displaying the few columns associated with the tickers.

The loop runs as designed outside the Dash framework. Below is the loop:

```
from yahoo_fin.stock_info import get_analysts_info, get_stats, get_live_price, get_quote_table
import pandas as pd

tickers = ['aapl', 'ayx']

stocks = pd.DataFrame(columns = ['ticker', 'yahoo_live_price',  'closing_price', '52_Week_High', '52_Week_Low','Percent_above_52_low', 'Percent_below_52_high'])

for ticker in tickers:
    df = get_stats(ticker)
    df['ticker'] = ticker
    df = df.pivot(index = 'ticker', columns = 'Attribute', values = 'Value')
    df['closing_price'] = get_quote_table(ticker)['Previous Close']
    df['yahoo_live_price'] = get_live_price(ticker)
    df = df[['yahoo_live_price','closing_price', '52 Week High 3', '52 Week Low 3']]
    df[['52 Week High 3', '52 Week Low 3']] = df[['52 Week High 3', '52 Week Low 3']].astype('float')
    df['percent_above_52_low'] = round((((df['closing_price'] - df['52 Week Low 3'])/df['closing_price']))*100,2)
    df['percent_below_52_high'] = round((((df['52 Week High 3'] - df['closing_price'])/df['52 Week High 3']))*100,2)
    df = df.reset_index()
    df.columns = ('ticker', 'yahoo_live_price',  'closing_price', '52_Week_High', '52_Week_Low'
                                 , 'Percent_above_52_low', 'Percent_below_52_high')
    stocks = stocks.append(df, ignore_index = True)
```

This gives me exactly what I want.  However, this does not work in the Dash environment.  Currently the app will display only one ticker and once that is displayed, will not change as the user changes. Does anyone spot what I'm doing wrong?  Full dash code below:

```
from yahoo_fin.stock_info import get_analysts_info, get_stats, get_live_price, get_quote_table
import dash
import dash_core_components as dcc
import dash_html_components as html
import dash_table
import pandas as pd
from dash.dependencies import Input, Output

app = dash.Dash()

app.layout = html.Div(children=[
    html.Div(children='''
        Symbols to grab:
    '''),
    dcc.Input(id='input', value='', type='text'),
    html.Div(id='table'),
])

@app.callback(
    Output(component_id='table', component_property='children'),
    [Input(component_id='input', component_property='value')]
)

def update_value(input_data):
    tickers = [input_data]

    stocks = pd.DataFrame(columns = ['ticker', 'yahoo_live_price',  'closing_price', '52_Week_High', '52_Week_Low','Percent_above_52_low', 'Percent_below_52_high'])


    for ticker in tickers:
        df = get_stats(ticker)
        df['ticker'] = ticker
        df = df.pivot(index = 'ticker', columns = 'Attribute', values = 'Value')
        df['closing_price'] = get_quote_table(ticker)['Previous Close']
        df['yahoo_live_price'] = get_live_price(ticker)
        df = df[['yahoo_live_price','closing_price', '52 Week High 3', '52 Week Low 3']]
        df[['52 Week High 3', '52 Week Low 3']] = df[['52 Week High 3', '52 Week Low 3']].astype('float')
        df['percent_above_52_low'] = round((((df['closing_price'] - df['52 Week Low 3'])/df['closing_price']))*100,2)
        df['percent_below_52_high'] = round((((df['52 Week High 3'] - df['closing_price'])/df['52 Week High 3']))*100,2)
        df = df.reset_index()
        df.columns = ('ticker', 'yahoo_live_price',  'closing_price', '52_Week_High', '52_Week_Low'
                                     , 'Percent_above_52_low', 'Percent_below_52_high')
        stocks = stocks.append(df, ignore_index = True)

    return dash_table.DataTable(
        id='table',
        columns=[{"name": i, "id": i} for i in stocks.columns],
        data=df.to_dict('records'),
    )

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run_server(debug = False)
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks like the problem is coming from how you format the `tickers` variable. In your working example, you have `tickers = ['aapl', 'ayx']`. In your callback, however, that ends up like this:

`tickers = ['aapl, ayx']`

It's a single string that contains the comma-separated values. So what happens is your loop only detects a single item, that one string. You need to break up the input string so that you have the proper format of one string for each stock, and the list will then have a `len()` that matches the number of stocks entered.